# As Easy as One-Two-Three

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, integer

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer. You can assume the input is valid and may take it as a string. If the number is any of

```
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
```

then output a [truthy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997) value. Otherwise, output a [falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/26997) value. For example, the inputs

```
1
2
3
12
122
124
132
321
457
777
890
900
1011
1230
1234
```

must all result in falsy output. (The input will not have leading zeroes so you needn't worry about things like `012`.)

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: Oh, strings are allowed? What about digit arrays?

Comment: @Dennis No. Let's keep it to plain strings or plain ints.

Comment: If I take string input, should I handle `012`?

Comment: Does it have to return the same truth value? same false value?

Comment: @Lynn No. `012` would be falsy but you can assume it is not input.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills No. It should just satisfy the linked definition of truthy/falsy - http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey/2194#2194

Answer (score 49):

### Python, 24 bytes

```python
range(123,790,111).count
```

An anonymous function that outputs 0 or 1. It creates the list `[123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789]` and counts how many times the input appears.

```python
f=range(123,790,111).count

f(123)
=> 1
f(258)
=> 0
```

Comment: Couldn't you remove a byte by making the start at 12 instead of 123?

Comment: It needs to not include 12.

Comment: But we can assume it wouldn't be input? I'm confused

Comment: If you're talking about the comments, they're saying that if you take input as a string (which this is not), you can expect numbers to not have leading zeroes, so 12 will be given as "12" and not "012".

Answer (score 35):

### Python, 24 bytes

```py
lambda n:n%111==12<n<900
```

Just a lot of condition chaining.

Comment: Being able to compare a range that easily beats any language I already know. I had to [look it up](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) to see how it worked.

Comment: Wow, if it wasn't for the word `lambda` I wouldn't have even guessed that was Python. That's horrific.

Answer (score 25):

### Haskell, 22 bytes

```haskell
(`elem`[123,234..789])
```

An anonymous function. Generates the evenly-spaced list `[123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789]` and checks if the input is an element.

Comment: No way! That's magic!

Answer (score 13):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
h:2j:12+?
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=aDoyajoxMis_&input=MTIz) or [Verify all test-cases.](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=Ons6MiYsInRydWUuIkB3OyJmYWxzZS4iQHd9YQpoOjJqOjEyKz8&input=WzEyMzoyMzQ6MzQ1OjQ1Njo1Njc6Njc4Ojc4OToxOjI6MzoxMjoxMjI6MTI0OjEzMjozMjE6NDU3Ojc3Nzo4OTA6OTAwOjEyMzA6MTIzNF0)

[Credits to Dennis for the algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91604/48934).

In English, "(prove that) the Input's first digit, concatenated to itself twice, add 12, is still the Input."

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, 25 bytes

```python
lambda n:`n-12`==`n`[0]*3
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/dH6JE0).

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) 76 + 3 = 79 bytes

This answer is a golf of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91609/56656) answer.  I don't actually know quite how my answer works but DJMcMayhem gives a good explanation in his original answer and my answer is a modification of his.

```
([]<>)<>({}[({})]<>)<>(({}[({})()()()()()]<>{}{}<(())>)){{}{}(((<{}>)))}{}{}
```

It is run with the -a ascii flag adding 3 bytes.

### Explanation (of sorts)

Starting with the original working solution:

```
([]<>)<>({}[({})]<>)<>({}[({})]<>)({}{}[()()])({}<({}[()()()])>)(({}{}<(())>)){{}{}(((<{}>)))}{}{}
```

I run this through a simple golfing algorithm I wrote and get:

```
([]<>)<>({}[({})]<>)<>(({}[({})]<>{}[()()]<({}[()()()])>{}<(())>)){{}{}(((<{}>)))}{}{}
```

From here I see the section `<({}[()()()])>{}` this essentially multiplies by one which makes it equal to `{}[()()()]` reduce the whole code to:

```
([]<>)<>({}[({})]<>)<>(({}[({})]<>{}[()()]{}[()()()]<(())>)){{}{}(((<{}>)))}{}{}
```

Lastly negatives can be combined:

```
([]<>)<>({}[({})]<>)<>(({}[({})()()()()()]<>{}{}<(())>)){{}{}(((<{}>)))}{}{}
```

Comment: *"I don't actually know quite how my answer works"* you win the internet

Comment: [Nope](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdPD4pPD4oe31bKHt9KV08Pik8Pigoe31bKHt9KSgpKCkoKSgpKCldPD57fXt9PCgoKSk-KSl7e317fSgoKDx7fT4pKSl9e317fQ&input=MTQz&args=LWE).

Comment: @LeakyNun I don't believe Ascii mode works on try it online.  You are going to have to get the github version.

Comment: It works, I'm saying that the algorithm is wrong.

Comment: @WheatWizard ASCII mode definitely works on TIO. You can verify this by [adding 48 ('0') to the top of the stack](http://bit.ly/2byiHdW). Leaky nun is right, the algorithm (*my* algorithm) is wrong, because it just checks if the sum of the differences is 2 (which works if the difference is +3 and -1). Unfortunately, both of our answers are wrong.

Comment: @WheatWizard This answer does not appear to be valid. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#PcmxDYBADEPRdeyCAmijLHK64uawPHvISYCsXzy5MGYkIyGPjq8@4l8fshwAmaQ2AITcojerzuuuYz0 "Brain-Flak – TIO Nexus") (My original answer wasn't either)

Answer (score 8):

## Brainfuck, 32 bytes

```
+>,+>,>,-[-<-<->>],[<]<[<]<[<]<.
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=Kz4sKz4sPiwtWy08LTwtPj5dLFs8XTxbPF08WzxdPC4&input=MTIz)

[Credits to Lynn for the core of the algorithm.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91617/48934)

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), 5 bytes

```
¥XX‚Q
```

**Explanation**

```
¥      # deltas
    Q  # are equal to
 XX‚   # [1,1]
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wqVYWOKAmlE&input=NDU2)

Comment: I used `2Å1` instead of `XX,`, just for the heck of less commands (4 instead of 5).

Comment: @ErikGolferエリックゴルファー: and `Å` is writeable on my keyboard (as opposed to `‚`) which is a benefit :)

Comment: `‚` (not the `,` I used) doesn't have a compose-key sequence too, while `Å` is `oA` on an en-US keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
DI⁼1,1
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=REnigbwxLDE&input=&args=NDU2) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=REnigbwxLDEKMTAwMDBSw4fDkGY&input=).

#### How it works

```
DI⁼1,1  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

D       Decimal; convert n to base 10.
 I      Increments; compute the differences of all pairs of adjacent digits.
   1,1  Yield [1, 1].
  ⁼     Test the results to both sides for equality.
```

Comment: 012 doesn't return false, although it doesn't actually return anything...

Comment: The input has to be an integer. As far as `ast.literal_eval` is concerned, [`012` doesn't represent an integer](http://ideone.com/dT8dVk).

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
d1=tn2=*
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ZDE9dG4yPSo&input=JzEyMyc)

This will print `1 1` for a truthy input, and an array with a `0` in it for a falsy value, since that is falsy in MATL.

Explanation:

```
d           % Calculate the difference between consecutive digits
 1=         % Push an array of which elements equal one
   t        % Duplicate this array
    n       % Push the length of this array
     2=     % Push a one if the length is 2, and a zero otherwise
            % Now, if we have a truthy input, the stack looks like:
            %   [1 1]
            %   1
            % And if we have a falsy input, the stack looks something like this:
            %   [1 0]
            %   1
            % Or this:
            %   [1 1]
            %   0
       *    % Multiply the top two elements
```

Comment: Maybe `d1=Ep4=` (I haven't tested thoroughly)

Comment: Or `dTTX=` for 5 bytes

Comment: @luismendo whaaa? How does that even work? I can't find documentation on `T`

Comment: `T` is the literal `true`, and `F` is `false`. Neighbouring `T` and `F` stick together, so `TT` is `[true true]`, which for these purposes is equivalent to `[1 1]`. See section 4.3 of the [spec](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/blob/master/doc/MATL_spec.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

### Java 7, 46 bytes

```
boolean f(int a){return a>12&a<790&a%111==12;}
```

After trying several things with Leaky Nun in chat, this seems to be the shortest. Sometimes you just have to do things the straightforward way :/

Explanation:

```
boolean f(int a){
    return a>12         Is it more than 12? (stupid edge case)
           &
           a<790        Is it in range the other way? 
           &
           a%111==12;   Is it 12 more than a multiple of 111? 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>35 29 24 21</s>  19 bytes

```perl6
{.chars==3&&'0123456789'.index: $_}
{$_ (elem) (123,*+111...789)}
{$_∈(123,*+111...789)}
*∈(123,*+111...789)
*∈(123,234...789)
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
# Whatever lambda ( the parameter is ｢*｣ )
*

∈ # is it an element of:

# this sequence
(
  123,
  234,

  # deduce rest of sequence
  ...

  # stop when you generate this value
  789
)
```

### Usage:

```perl6
my &code = *∈(123,234...789);

say code 123; # True
say code 472; # False

say (  *∈(123,234...789)  )( 789 ); # True
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 26

```
.
$*: 
^(:+ ):\1::\1$
```

Outputs 1 for truthy and 0 for falsey.

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAouCiQqOiAKXig6KyApOlwxOjpcMSQ&input=MTIzCjIzNAozNDUKNDU2CjU2Nwo2NzgKNzg5CjEKMgozCjEyCjEyMgoxMjQKMTMyCjMyMQo0NTcKNzc3Cjg5MAo5MDAKMTAxMQoxMjMwCjEyMzQ) (First line added to allow multiple testcases to be run).

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 99 bytes

```
([{}]({})<>)<>([{}]{}<>)(({})<([{}]{})((){[()](<{}>)}{})>)([{}]{})((){[()](<{}>)}{})<>{{{}}<>{}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68RXV0bq1Fdq2ljB0RgXnUtkK0BFoPygTzN6mgNzVgNm@paO81aoAhQBU45G7vq6upaoClg4v9/QyPj/7qJAA)

This is 98 bytes of code `+1` for the `-a` flag.

This prints `1` for truthy, and either `0` or nothing (which is equivalent to 0) for falsy

Comment: Try to get rid of push pop inefficiencies.  I can see a bunch in your code.  They look like `...)({}` but vary.  If you push and pop without using the value you can condense it into one thing. I can link you to a version of your code with all of these golfed out if you want.

Comment: [Here](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdPD4pPD4oe31bKHt9KV08Pik8Pigoe31bKHt9KSgpKCkoKSgpKCldPD57fXt9PCgoKSk-KSl7e317fSgoKDx7fT4pKSl9e317fQ&input=) is my 76 byte golf of your program. I pretty much ran my brain-flak optimizer over your code with a few custom settings.

Comment: [Nope](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdPD4pPD4oe31bKHt9KV08Pik8Pih7fVsoe30pXTw-KSh7fXt9WygpKCldKSh7fTwoe31bKCkoKSgpXSk-KSgoe317fTwoKCkpPikpe3t9e30oKCg8e30-KSkpfXt9e30&input=MTQz&args=LWE).

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby `-nl`, <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 25 bytes

```ruby
p"123456789"[$_]&.size==3
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5ejlLsgqWlJWm6FjsLlAyNjE1MzcwtLJWiVeJj1fSKM6tSbW2NIfJQZQtuBgOVcQFVcgEVcwHVcwG1cAF1cQE1chlyGXEZcxkaAREIm3AZGgMFjAyBCs25zM3NuSwsDbgsDQy4DA0MDYEKjA1AhAnEbAA)

Comment: Your tests show 12 going to true.

Comment: @xnor Oops. That'll teach me to golf after bedtime. Fixed!

Comment: I thought `-a` does a `split`, not `chop`? Also, what does the `&` do? I'm using an older Ruby which throws an error. Anyway, it works perfectly at 26 bytes without it.

Comment: Oops, I meant `-l`, not `-a`. `&.` is the "safe navigation" operator, added in Ruby 2.3. Without it inputs like `19`, which aren't substrings if `"123456789"`, will raise a NoMethodError.

Comment: @Jordan I'm not getting an error in 2.2. Maybe it's new in 2.3 too?

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>30</s> 22 bytes

```
scan()%in%(12+1:7*111)
```

Not particularly exciting; check if input is in the sequence given by 12 + 111k, where k is each of 1 to 7. Note that `:` precedes `*` so the multiplication happens after the sequence is generated.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 114 bytes

```
([((()()()){}){}]{})(((()()()){}())<>)<>{({}<(({}[(((((()()()){}()){}){}){}){}]())){(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}{}>[()])}<>
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFsoKCgpKCkoKSl7fSl7fV17fSkoKCgoKSgpKCkpe30oKSk8Pik8Pnsoe308KCh7fVsoKCgoKCgpKCkoKSl7fSgpKXt9KXt9KXt9KXt9XSgpKSl7KDx7fT4pPD4oe31bKCldKTw-fXt9PlsoKV0pfTw-&input=MTIz)

Correct version (in the spirit of the question): takes the integer as input, output 0 for falsey and 1 for truthy.

This is **not** stack clean.

#### Algorithm

Let the input be `n`.

The output is truthy iff `(n-123)(n-234)(n-345)(n-456)(n-567)(n-678)(n-789)=0`.

I computed those seven numbers by first subtracting 12 and then subtract 111 7 times, and then computed the logical double-NOT of those seven numbers and added them up.

For truthy results, the sum is 6; for falsey results, the sum is 7.

Then, I subtract the sum from 7 and output the answer.

Comment: I don't understand the code, but the algorithm is clever so have a +1.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>41 30</s> 23 bytes

First code-golf submission, be gentle :)

```
a=>{return a>12&&a<790?a%111==12:false;};
a=>a>12&&a<790?a%111==12:false
a=>a>12&a<790&a%111==12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq7CoQwEAXQfr9impUEXZixEUkm5Vbbbx2DgQuSgI/vj5YHTjo@6UD7XiV5lHNYat0CZW1RQwwydtFPM3fxLSKqMjb3ynU3TyUoO5AnYWZH6HuLbLKBtf8d5/pDWR@4dgM)

- -11 bytes thanks to Kirill L.
- Another -7 bytes thanks to ASCII-only.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can save some bytes by dropping the curly braces and `return` keyword: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcuxCsMgEADQvV9xFBoUW7jLUho9s3Xq3tmKwkFQiOlU@u0mwxtfbLfYpD@/JTop2/VT6@Ihcw/sg6dxGIK7P3AOFyJipnHKYWmp21OuqzoGCKMVcECIaEGM0b/3Klt6SUlKwMAZpoOBrERr@@87)

Comment: [23](https://tio.run/##Dcq7CoQwEAXQfr9impUEXZixEUkm5Vbbbx2DgQuSgI/vj5YHTjo@6UD7XiV5lHNYat0CZW1RQwwydtFPM3fxLSKqMjb3ynU3TyUoO5AnYWZH6HuLbLKBtf8d5/pDWR@4dgM), [also 23](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsMgFAXQvV/xlgYlDTxLoYi@jJmyZzaicKEoJPb7TcYDJ55TPNGXf4kepb32Wn8zZelB5uC/lgcVJmv10xgj8v5098j1UHclCDuQJ8PMjjCOGlllBa23Ay2tKOmG6xc)

Comment: Nice first submission!

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>13</s> 9 bytes

```
A,s3ewqe=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@@@oU2ycWl6Yavv/v6GRMQA)

**Explanation**

```
A,s        e# Push "0123456789".
   3ew     e# Split it into contiguous length-3 chunks: ["012" "123" "234" ... "789"].
      q    e# Push the input.
       e=  e# Count the number of times the input appears in the array.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 43 bytes

```
,>,>,>,[>>]<[[-<-<->>]<+[>>]<++[>>->]<+<]>.
```

Bah, I'm no good at this. Outputs `\x01` if the output is one of the strings `123`, `234`, …, `789`; outputs `\x00` otherwise.

(I beat Java 7, though…)

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LD4sPiw-LFs-Pl08W1stPC08LT4-XTwrWz4-XTwrK1s-Pi0-XTwrPF0-Lg&input=MzQ1&debug=on)

Comment: What's the point of `[>>]<`? Couldn't that just be `>`?

Comment: I want to veer the program into failure (by throwing it off-track) if the cell under the pointer *isn't* zero at that point.

Comment: [42 bytes](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=Kz4sPiw-LFstPC08LT4-XSxbWy1dPl08K1tbLV0-XTwrK1tbLV0-XTwu&input=MTIz)

Comment: @LeakyNun That looks completely different; feel free to post it as a separate answer

Comment: @Lynn [Done.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91623/48934)

Comment: You beat Java 7, yes, but not Java 8 :P

Answer (score 3):

## Excel - <strike>62</strike> <strike>57</strike> <strike>35</strike> 31 bytes

Based on Anastasiya-Romanova's answer, but returning Excel's `TRUE/FALSE` values.

```
=AND(LEN(N)=3,MID(N,2,1)-MID(N,1,1)=1,MID(N,3,1)-MID(N,2,1)=1)
```

Further, we can get to

```
=AND(LEN(N)=3,MID(N,2,1)-LEFT(N)=1,RIGHT(N)-MID(N,2,1)=1)
```

since both `RIGHT` and `LEFT` return a single character by default.

And, inspired by some of the Python solutions:

```
=AND(LEN(N)=3,MOD(N,111)=12,N<>900)
```

Thanks to Neil for 4 more bytes...

```
=AND(N>99,MOD(N,111)=12,N<900)
```

Comment: Doesn't `N<900` save you a byte, in which case you can also use `N>99` instead of `LEN(N)=3`.

Comment: 21 bytes: `=REPT(LEFT(N),3)+12=N` where `N` is the name of the reference cell.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 26 bytes

`n=>1>(n-12)%111&n>99&n<790`

This takes advantage of the fact that I'm using bit-wise logic operators on what are essentially booleans (which are bit-based!)

Thanks to Titus for saving 2.

Comment: two bytes: `(n-12)` and `n>99`

Comment: @Titus Oh, very nice, +1 to you!

Comment: => is ES6, not ES5.

Comment: @Neil well spotted, thanks

Comment: I believe it was decided in meta that you didn't have to count "f=" making this 26 bytes

Comment: Thanks @CharlieWynn, is that because the function's declaration and assignment are arbitrary?

Comment: @WallyWest I think it's because it's not necessary to have "f=" to use the function in every case, so why assume you need it for this case?  People smarted than me decided it's fine so I just go with it ;)

Comment: Guess I'll be going through all my previous answers!

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 7 bytes

```
ẹ~⟦₂-_2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9w1866R/OXPWpq0o03@v/fxNQMAA)

### Explanation

```
ẹ~⟦₂-_2
ẹ        Split into digits
 ~⟦₂     Assert that this is an increasing range; take its endpoints
    -_2  Assert that the starting minus ending endpoint is -2
```

As a full program, we get a truthy return if all assertions hold, a falsey return if any fail.

Answer (score 3):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 20 bytes

The input *n* is in unary, as the length of a string of `x`s.

```
^x{12}(x{111}){1,7}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NTgIxFEZfBScG7gVmoEg0oRZXLti40KXRpIFL52rpNG35kWGefRwWJm6@zfmSk/OlDzquA/uUR88bCrvKfdNPG5SjY@@VzPPJA5zVcjJsP0@1mDXQrRAN1mL80Ny2w8kZi1S9pcDOABbR8prgfpzPEWVUU3ks2RKAVYH0xrIjQLxRbm8t1kbZInrLCQb5ACVvAZwyhSVnUonL2eXC8UW/ACuvQ6SVS2Depx@If4D@A7cUT2JxxZjKUB2zlTtoy5te0M7QopeNrNxWASQ/KpI8GmEnzE5ZEciTTsBY7HRalxAQ69jv@y4pwbVCSL9PMYXuIpumneZidjf/BQ)

This works by asserting that \$n-12\$ is of the form \$111k\$ where \$1\le k\le 7\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
¯k₁⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiwq9r4oKB4oG8IiwiIiwiMTIzXG4yMzRcbjFcbjJcbjNcbjEyMzQiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
¯k₁⁼
¯    # Deltas
 k₁  # [1,1]
   ⁼ # compare lists
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 15 bytes

```
{($x-12)=3#*$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWUKnQNTTStDVW1lKpqOXiSos2NDKOBVImBgYgysjYBMwzNQNR5haWEB5YzhAkCQBJFhD+)

Port of [Dennis' algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91604/107017).

Explanation:

```
{($x-12)=3#*$x}  Main function. Takes x as input
            $x   Convert x to string
           *     Then get the first character
         3#      And duplicate it thrice
        =        Is it equal to
 ( x-12)         x - 12
  $              Converted to string?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel - 104 bytes

```
=IF(LEN(N)<3,"Falsy",IF(AND(LEN(N)=3,MID(N,2,1)-MID(N,1,1)=1,MID(N,3,1)-MID(N,2,1)=1),"Truthy","Falsy"))
```

**Explanation:**

The syntax for the IF formula in Excel is:

```
IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )
```

If the length of input `N`, where it's a name of the reference cell, is less than 3, then it will return **Falsy**. Else, if the length of input `N` is 3 and both of the difference of second digit and first digit and the difference of third digit and second digit are equal to 1, then it will return **Truthy**.

Comment: 21 bytes: `=REPT(LEFT(N),3)+12=N` where `N` is the name of the reference cell.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 8 Bytes

```
qi>3SeQT
```

[Try online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qi%3E3SeQT&input=234&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
q       Q  Is the input equal to:
  <3S       The last three digits of the range from 1 to
     eQ      The last digit of the input    
 i     T      Concatenated together into an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 10 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Takes string argument.

```apl
1 1≡¯2-/⍎¨
```

`1 1≡` Is {1, 1} identical to

`¯2-/` the reversed pair-wise difference of

`⍎¨` each character taken as a number?

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=e%u2190%7B%7B1%3D%u2374%u2375%3A%u236C%u2374%u2375%u22C4%u2375%7D%u2283%7B%u237A/%u2375%7D/%u2395VFI%20%u2375%7D%20%u22C4%20f%u21901%201%u2261%AF2-/e%A8%20%u22C4%20f%A8%2C%A8%27123%27%20%27234%27%20%27345%27%20%27456%27%20%27567%27%20%27678%27%20%27789%27%20%271%27%20%272%27%20%273%27%20%2712%27%20%27122%27%20%27124%27%20%27132%27%20%27321%27%20%27457%27%20%27777%27%20%27890%27%20%27900%27%20%271011%27%20%271230%27%20%271234%27&run) (`⍎` has been emulated with `e` for security reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 18 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the input on STDIN

```
123.pl <<< 123
```

`123.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=$_=/./.2==$_-$&x3
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 31 bytes

```
<?=($n=$_GET[n])-12==$n[0]*111;
```

Check if first digit of (number minus 12) is multiple of 111

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v3+, 24 bytes

```
($args[0]-12)/111-in1..7
```

Uses the same *"multiple of 111 plus 12"* trick as some other answers, but goes the other direction. Takes input `$args[0]`, subtracts `12`, divides by `111`, and checks whether that's `-in` the range `1..7`. Outputs a Boolean true/false value. Requires v3+ for the `-in` operator.

#### Test Cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 123,234,345,456,567,678,789|%{.\easy-as-one-two-three.ps1 $_}
True
True
True
True
True
True
True

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 1,2,3,12,122,124,132,321,457,777,890,900,1011,1230,1234|%{.\easy-as-one-two-three.ps1 $_}
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 2):

## ARM Machine Code, 18 bytes

Hex dump (little endian):

```
3803 d105 6808 ebc0 2010 b280 f2a0 1001 4770
```

This is a function that takes in a length, pointer pair for the string. The output is bash-style, it outputs 0 for true and a non-zero value for false. In C the function would be declared int oneTwoThree(size_t length, char* string). The instruction encoding is thumb-2, which has 2 and 4 byte instructions. Tested on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Ungolfed assembly:

```
.syntax unified
.text
.global oneTwoThree
.thumb_func
oneTwoThree:
    @Input: r0 - the number of characters in the string
    @r1 - A pointer to the (not necessarily NUL-terminated)
    @string representation of the number (char*)
    @Output: r1 - 0 if the number is in 123,234,...,789, else non-zero (bash-style)
    subs r0,r0,#3
    bne end @Return non-zero if r0!=3
    ldr r0,[r1] @Remember that this is little endian
    @So the first digit is the most siginificant byte
    @I.e. if the input was 123 then r0 contains 0xXY010203 where XY is garbage

    rsb r0,r0,r0,lsr #8 @r0=(r0>>8)-r0 (rsb is reverse subtract)
    uxth r0,r0 @r0&=((1<<16)-1) (mask off top half)
    @Now r0 is 0x0101 iff we have a matching number
    sub r0,r0,#0x101
    @Now r0 is 0 iff the string fit the specification

    end:
    bx lr @return
```

Testing script (also assembly):

```
.syntax unified
.text
.global main
.thumb_func
main:
    push {r4,lr}
    ldr r4,[r1,#4] @r0=argv[1]
    mov r0,r4
    bl strlen
    @Now r0 is the length of the string argv[1]
    mov r1,r4
    bl oneTwoThree @oneTwoThree(strlen(argv[1]),argv[1])
    cmp r0,#0
    it ne
    movne r0,#1 @Output through return code, 1 if false
    pop {r4,pc}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

And one more option in JS. Takes input as a string and outputs `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

```
n=>++n[0]==n[1]&++n[1]==n[2]&!n[3]
```

See my other solutions [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91599/as-easy-as-one-two-three/119612#119612) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91599/as-easy-as-one-two-three/119595#119595)

---

### Try it

```js
f=
n=>++n[0]==n[1]&++n[1]==n[2]&!n[3]
i.addEventListener("input",_=>o.innerText=f(i.value))
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
9ṡ3Vċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/5cOdC47Aj3f///zc0MgYA)

Comment: Yay outgolfed the Dennis with a perfectly competing answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 4 bytes

```
~s₃Ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8rysGqnm4u@v//2glQyNjJR0FJUMQYWRsAqZAhLGJKZgCESamZmA1YAlTM3MIB8wzM7eA8MA6zS0swTxjiBFGhhDdYA3m5mDKwtIARFkagClDA0NDiH5jAyhtohQLAA)

Certainly not as creative as user62131's answer, but quite a bit shorter. Takes input as a string through the input variable and assumes the string has no leading zeroes (i.e. `"012"` is a false positive), outputting through success or failure, where success of a predicate run as a program prints `true.` and failure prints `false.`

```
        The input is a
~s₃     length-3 substring of
   Ị    "0123456789".
```

If input is allowed to be a bit less orthodox...

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
Ịs₃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX133qG3Do6bmRx3LlUqKSlP1lGpAzLTEnGIgu/bhrs7ah1sn/H@4u6sYqOr//2glQyNjJR0FJUMQYWRsAqZAhLGJKZgCESamZmA1YAlTM3MIB8wzM7eA8MA6zS0swTxjiBFGhhDdYA3m5mDKwtIARFkagClDA0NDiH5jAyhtohQLAA)

Outputs the same way and takes input in the same format, but takes it through the output variable. To run this as a program, the input is [given as the first command-line argument on TIO](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@HuruJHTc3///9XMjQyVgIA), rather than through the Input box (which actually has to either be empty or contain `"0123456789"`).

Answer (score 2):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA), 15 bytes

```
Ci,:::SSL{+,SS=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7c9s2Ev9fnwK1r7VUS7bsJE2is9zGSXp1m8QZy53rjcdlIRGymJIEQ4KWPWn71XO74EMECYlg/PRMG5sEdn/7xAJYBldixv1Hz4Lws@MFPBQkuoq6xKNi1pqG3CPC8RjJXrmMBcnjkPo2/JO@wL/gv3PWSh@IkE7YmE7@bLUmLo0ichDSaEJf4u@DFoGftbW1kYABXRKycycSLIwIUCEXNHTo2GURDJADbTYlluX4jrCsdsTcaWfQki/wZ13SkBNzMvlLHLwVyQFDcnqmPqfwrK8@GiuPFjxehIzMGTCgtuOfE3bBQtAa/kojMplRkBX5fl9mHMIQy@M2A7o/UjdiBdzvnYDZPccnNhU0f@xMic@lCWA6MNtyIirEVbszyIcU6MMAC6cD@cUMRNnunA4GvZ0zZdKUh8TqEosAU@bHHgupYO0SqRIjDTO0VxS7Apmqb06RZbfytIxDtcwWDQLm220e2u2EcKeTD2egszrJwUsWWv2JohOlxhkz5pMAjCCYTa6YKNmHuqiqKysbUbXRycyJyNxxXRIJDj5A4TcxY2QMBv@TCRLwyBEO90seN585LrNczoMIiH76W6HIyAQdAh0WSQUcmYcqARxhpW@qXjpJHKoot3wOkec6E4gSsG0ujH6E4IEq7vr7OJoRmDgGjoJLaNI8eQQGMMBKBkif6eLogrdULYrvi9QvqBszwqeLiEFOGi74PuWBv65kgm4jB3WWCzLmQkCqAs4rxbKScXXSOX7EQtHuJ0PqBTRCgDNU/sslXwCoCg92ldm5xIIHWeIsJ5qcrBpmIRNx6Bc8rxqJ6ZACMGSTxG4JTa0KeFAU/g5g9jONjSCMEVC2eOSYIias7GFqkuxPFV/2lAwhJumaJl3RLFUuFJRgLc8e62aPq7MLPlfEvhGlLqgNYEx2NyWREoKJjB293P2m4lZJjzt6pfRTEx7jehwxrcjyTdmpCnyyEZ2clvQWJOUy/1zM9A6bvCvTTV0NXrYXLAqhGbuw4EpqcoUguEIQF/RB2uV1o5OzGseOaycPy/wE8wK1sMEnFtQdSs2hvoSF0WUfYy6YYh0sDrLlDJIP9zxcoaqVAi4@pRoBzFohvU/61UKiMqo3JDvKKOkjVZzD5dRKspaBZYKgu52uJauuMi@dqCefuWGmmE4VbJHBWSMG4B0hFlGSkZoZllUTp3LOGUzKENVPyUbiLDl9tQwba7WaPgljVm/bIdldzemPxuYoDquAMKWPE@vJp97Uwj3I6AoylkdoeA6R4AvYvgRyz4RlIGxptoIrMiV7U1C5Tz22X307IXsYNvut1gmHeMLNDYT2OD7vkhjy1tTenmCoARdqY76Zbk@2cGjk8jmx@dwnPBZBLNLh0fYkksAc3BchT8uSEluWR6EutlITJgDAEIWtV@pkKba8klz7/NLpDgaD0ejNp83uaDT8nO7QktxFDjAJJVkRc5ZHgyKZYorK0h15C1DkaPl3kvAKbPPydk/my8KbYoILr1RT5fYtkjrVkD0rJ4J0jLInW@pslQfrRC62e5AL99WidUW@6WtCqaC1YkHdr8Z@xZ93zMntGJDbNSe3a0DukTm5RwbkHpuTe2xA7ok5uScG5L4zJ/edAbmn5uSeGpB7Zk7umQG55@bknhuQcxu4sUlYvGlAz8TzWIO4MDHu6waBYRJodoPIMDHvqwa@bBIbswbuYuLNPzXxFxOH@aURQROKn9YGZP0Vm4QM6wNT4tkjrPx6Jhn7b2Rz6F@DzaYJmxDZyOXuWB7o6vjQxQqsr1wlGJNBuO9wcJ8hT4/b4y6hgFJvoSUSOp1WdcGWAiSrPdRLMxrWCr7xx8ZKx1CPc7VFsFE1XZZCnnbVlDObO2edVYSUimoTd1VVjbyluJsNcC/HC2fkS7Fvoh@8sO1bdgCdy25SAz/tIb5RPMabBnEPIHsmIL9FkG9jVziBe3UPIL81AbmdJBbBzsF7bOfCiXQ7y9sHu71tgvZrqVJuxy6/B4xfm0D8HSG@vgy4vyxR37LVjcweyQD6GF4HYZU5XhxuTWHjl/4aAYM27XR0SfrAEXMHtrQNstI/CPrd0cmNYv7HRF3fyHz47tU92PMbE3x/Ib6j43uA95cJPAvh/XYv@H4HfBrvG2k38RXgFIEH8qydL86vX6wsFYp3B0DAQD1jLZcDcy5jEy4vJJfsWsZMGPXewEyaAz2fgwZ8jOTpIp/0DH/JoYzCITvsryU8QMJ2jNel8sweROHTFRy@NPPQ64ysoP63inpx5WYKPLuFM0WVjac3MKEijYfSePxCVT/GR0JEyzK5APsiY2TYJAkDfG9zfCVFy/u39OCzHl9TnRvjC2r0R3zZ2xPp/cLjsS9Md3D@YgfX7yZTV@zhjG10M3Z6X2OnB6SH1b5wTX/4XibLpG0rbZDo93Z2n5r6Xd7j1YZ9ZvlcoWMA4Kt8jVvcrdYmbc1ZRnr7asLyX8gymtNAGlrMOXEE8yLC/Wsn81vP@GMD@Y6lTbnIFikxCxm7Wxknt66IyXVUpr3PqehxhHqccB/XTT9XJrhLQji6ez/BGIsEirSJ/1CjCDsvi7HcAdLmAWSzsbH1gTu@ZOd3FoksP/jCNoblSW@CaQ6SSSH1Fa700tn1J3pNlIPgDdThpOqAsk8QIOI4mPLT3Nfu6c7HFaG6aYpW2iAUuZaLBVCSyftD8vhZ2tmKf@8NyZOny@cpJ47A4lQiwdt7OR1A18t9WJR70QuXaKC9eWdy91Wxn3@x1AC5VS/2pSx/HSAS2vUl@0q/q9D@rUjbpLA2WdQrXGLk8qvfG2lJ@qZliGzcSaK52Uk6JAPbJM/8muI8X4qzmFMuk5xyWckprTo3ULubblpMzZnA4faRgaNxedQiezKwA/zF6OXhYdrpWOd1i1aESvvx0naEkijVvmXtZQT@yCHtyUy9Bup0Iazt4caGgaWPlopqEgT3L20efE2E9lWh0wz6cA1cNG4DMd8tF/OhGldj2IXAmnh@yX0Rcpf86PJ5vUL2UCFvWBRBHU1v@wYE1bdHGyWuHT0lZqLqpu1G@6iL/4B5ZBv73ahj/@GqYyivdD7G4NZ3oIjh8MFqYuN/G6CJAybmjPkPYWuJ@sLqcoL/e7gO9AM60AkLPQc3Zq2bSYr41Re7dIRJbbmOACAf2rIdmLrkQ@wFNYldah312q/VR7UFoRbRB0T0M6DAam4OhXXUpMdB7Z@p5/Zzzg0/S2zGrqey2zRgd4rs/ottrz3ZM1vtva6qO6l5v8Kid@UGS9kp9XbOaiy0TKpcqGK/eG0zrVbas5K0sCTflqz7tyqqiSe9XN3VU/oOz6xT6MSQZvLlnqTZUncuyXcqUoogZPJAJso/WcXPItN2qGrXvL43Wt8ov36Cn7g4AkrDKZnPmA9bfA6MQxlVwgGbAtsp7N7tmv7oZv1W6qcsOZojZC17COS5siNa5sm80oSVgit1Kqy/lVco2Yeb5Q82jVIgu5ywQJBf2NWYQ@LBXpswjANR@v6pms3Tia/lP5C20ZAlcdZH3GPJB69z5gsyD7l/3sWTYD4H4xDgxFW4SSm99vr4@Oh4QHTTS3evyYT8k@4tSNceFRaAKx/CF0RIvgM4TB03/YSh1XTjsBirhAD4mGaHsfKe9xpHlXS4sgrRYMTQ12OsblZp3Z5tCXF9gC5o0ypZLblUn1VyK8RuLHK9uM1FXSom/nze2X30fw)

### Explanation

```
Ci                - Set implicit output to output numbers, and turn "0-9" into 0-9
  ,               - Reverse stack
   :::SSL{+       - First digit of input, concatenated to itself twice, + 12
           ,SS=   - Concatenate the digits of the original, then check if both numbers are equal
<implicit output> - Output 1 if truthy, 0 if falsy
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 26 bytes

```factor
[ "123456789"3 clump in? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FUzNCsIwGLvvKYIPIP3bvlYPHsWLF/EkHsaoY@C6rusYIj57bSEJIQl5tV2cQrrfLtfzAYuNC/owrX5wPXywMX58GFzEvOVyXq3r7IJjVc3bF1xICKkgVQ1VN6gbQkMapA04BGReZBQqcJkDwfOQQETQhsEwBs44L0@siMKvSg/sis1v2uwkuvc6egzuhGcaW499@gM)

- `"123456789" 3 clump` -> `{ "123" "234" "345" "456" "567" "678" "789" }`
- `in?` Is the input in this?

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 118 + 3 = 121 bytes

```
([][()()()]<>)<>({}[({})()]<>)<>({}[{}()]<>)<>(<{{}}>)<>([]){{}{(<{}>)<>({}())<>}{}([])}<>{(<{}>)<>({}[()])<>}<>({}())
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdWygpKCkoKV08Pik8Pih7fVsoe30pKCldPD4pPD4oe31be30oKV08Pik8Pig8e3t9fT4pPD4oW10pe3t9eyg8e30-KTw-KHt9KCkpPD59e30oW10pfTw-eyg8e30-KTw-KHt9WygpXSk8Pn08Pih7fSgpKQ&input=MTIz&args=LWE)

ASCII version: take code-points as input, output \x00 for falsey or \x01 for truthy.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 9 bytes

```
~ut{3Qlq&
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7Eut%7B3Qlq%26&input=%22123%22&warnings=0)

```
~ut{      -  input in "123456789" 
        & - ^ and V
    3Qlq  -  len(input) == 3
```

Or 5 bytes if allowed sequence input

```
$1D]q
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%241D%5Dq&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D&warnings=0)

```
$     - delta(input)
 1D]q - ^ == [1,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Fish (><>), 14 bytes

With input from the command line/initial stack.

```
l3=?!;$:@---0=l1==n;
```

Explanation:

```
$:@              Swaps top two values on stack then duplicates topmost one, then swaps top three values
   ---             Each '-' subtracts the second most value on the stack from the topmost and pushes their result
      0=l1=          Checks if topmost value is 0, pushes 1 if true and 0 if false, then checks if length of stack is 1 (pushes 1 is true, 0 if false) 
         =n;           Does the logical && of the top two truthy/falsy values pushed in previous step and outputs the result.
```

Try it [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)

Comment: This actually returns false-positives for a lot of inputs, including any three digit number where all three digits are the same like `111`. It also errors out without delivering a falsey if the initial input is less than three characters.

Comment: @CallumKerr You're right, I wrote this in a hurry. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>32</s> 34 bytes

```
<?=(800>$x=$argv[1]-12?:1)>$x%111;
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?=(800>$x=$argv[1]-12?:1)>$x%111;' | php -- 124
```

Updates:

- I made a little mistake where 12 was considered valid.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 49 bytes

```
@for /l %%a in (123,111,789)do @if %%a==%1 echo 1
```

Comment: You need `@` before `echo 1`

Answer (score 1):

## [3d](https://github.com/Moonstroke/3d), 61 bytes

```
>:&&#a&×∕$#a∕#a%.--v
  v--.%a#$∕a#&%×&a#—'F!,;
v —'F!;
>'T!;
```

Will output:

```
T
```

if input is a three consecutive increasing digits,

```
F
```

if not.

Explanation:

```
:&&  push imput and duplicate twice
#a&× push 0xa (10), duplicate it, multiply top two of the stack: get 100
∕    floor divide top two elements of the stack (we get the first digit)
$    invert top two elements
#a∕  floor divide by 10 (get rid of last digit)
#a%  modulo 10 (get middle digit)
.-   push 1 and difference
-    difference (hence we get 0 if two initial digits have a difference of 1)
—    is top of stack null?
if not:
'F!  print 'F'
,;   pops the stack and exits
if yes:
#a&× get 100
%    modulo (get rid of first digit)
&    duplicate
#a∕  floor divide by 10 (get middle digit)
$    invert
#a%  modulo 10 (get last digit)
.- push 1 and difference
-  difference
— is top of stack null?
yes:
'T!; print 'T' and exit
not:
'F!; print F and exit
```

Phew, this really ain't golfy.

Comment: Link to 3d? (filler text)

Comment: yeah, forgot it... Adding it now!

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8, 23 bytes

```
n->n<900&(n-122)%111==1
```

Ungolfed:

```
interface N { boolean f(int n); }

public static void main(String[] args) {
  N f = n ->
    n < 900 // 900 is not good
    &
    (n - 122) % 111 == 1 // force 12 to go negative and fail the comparison (can't use 123 because -111 % 111 == 0, while -110 % 111 == -1).
}
```

Test class:

```
public class Main {
  private interface N {

    boolean f(int n);
  }

  static void test(N f, int n, boolean expected) {
    boolean result = f.f(n);
    System.out.printf("%s -> %b (%b) -> %s%n", n, result, expected, result == expected ? "OK" : "NOK");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    N f = n->n<900&(n-122)%111==1;

    test(f,  123, true);
    test(f,  234, true);
    test(f,  345, true);
    test(f,  456, true);
    test(f,  678, true);
    test(f,  789, true);

    test(f,    1, false);
    test(f,    2, false);
    test(f,    3, false);
    test(f,   12, false);
    test(f,  122, false);
    test(f,  124, false);
    test(f,  132, false);
    test(f,  321, false);
    test(f,  457, false);
    test(f,  777, false);
    test(f,  890, false);
    test(f,  900, false);
    test(f, 1011, false);
    test(f, 1230, false);
    test(f, 1234, false);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES5), <strike>47</strike> 39 bytes

```
function(n){return(n-12)%111==0&&i<1e3}
```

Old solution with 47 did not work correctly.

Comment: Old one returns `true` for `1234`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

Just another JS option. Takes input as a string and outputs `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

```
n=>+n[2]&!n[3]&~"123456789".search(n)
```

See my other solutions [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91599/as-easy-as-one-two-three/119612#119612) and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91599/as-easy-as-one-two-three/119629#119629)

---

### Try it

```js
f=
n=>+n[2]&!n[3]&~"123456789".search(n)
i.addEventListener("input",_=>o.innerText=f(i.value))
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
%#o¥C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@6@qnH9oqfP//4ZGxgA)

Comment: I think you can change `12` to `C` to save a byte

Answer (score 1):

## 8086 Machine Code, 14 bytes

```
3C 03   CMP  AL, 3      ; check if input length is 3 chars exactly 
75 0A   JNZ  FALSY      ; if not, falsy  
AD      LODSW           ; load first char into AL, second into AH, advance SI 
40      INC  AX         ; increment first char 
3A E0   CMP  AH, AL     ; are chars now equal? 
75 04   JNZ  FALSY      ; if not, falsy
AC      LODSB           ; load third char into AL 
48      DEC  AX         ; decrement third char 
3A E0   CMP  AH, AL     ; are chars now equal?
FALSY:
```

Input string is `SI`, length in `AL`.  Return is Zero Flag where (`ZF=1`) if Truthy, (`ZF=0`) if Falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╡e╦ù┌
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b565cb97da&i=%22123%22%0A%22234%22%0A%22345%22%0A%22456%22%0A%22567%22%0A%22678%22%0A%22789%22%0A%221%22%0A%222%22%0A%223%22%0A%2212%22%0A%22122%22%0A%22124%22%0A%22132%22%0A%22321%22%0A%22457%22%0A%22777%22%0A%22890%22%0A%22900%22%0A%221011%22%0A%221230%22%0A%221234%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 23 bytes (thanks ASCII-only!)

```
n->n>12&n<790&n%111==12
```

Old version, 40 bytes

```java
n->n>99&n<999&"123456789".contains(n+"")
```

-1 bytes thanks to gwaugh
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYy9CoMwFIV3n@LiUBKKQv8rto5unRxLhxgTidUbMVEo4rOn8QVczoHz8Z2GTSxqqq/jLTMGXkzhHCi0YpCMC8jnUutWMARJ/ApI0yXox7JVHIxl1tekVQWd90hhB4X1@wNsqA2dgxwkPB1GGWZJssNH4jM8HE/ny/V2T8KYa7TeMwT3YUhdGhQ/Y0UX69HGvb@yLRIZS7IqlG7hTbrCZXF/)

Comment: This returns `Truthy` for input of `1234` or `4567`, etc. https://tio.run/##fYy9CoMwFEb3PMXFoSQUBe2vSB3dOjmWDjE1EhtvxEShiM9u4wO00wff4ZyWTzxsX@9VaG4t3LnCmSh09SC5qKGYK2N0zREk9S8gyxbSj5VWAqzjzs9k1As679HSDQqbxxP40Fg2kwIk3FYMc8zTdBfEyeF4Ol@uaRAJg84bluI@CNiakfJjXd1FZnRR7yNOI5WRpJvC2E@85f7gONngsqxf

Comment: @gwaugh fixed. Thanks.

Comment: you could -1 byte by changing `n<1000` to `n<999` (or even `n<790`) since the highest Truthy number is 789

Comment: @gwaugh done. Thanks again

Comment: [23](https://tio.run/##fcuxCoMwFIXhPU9xl0oclMYWSrE6unVyLB2iJhIbb8REoYjPnqYv4HTgfPwDX3kydB/fam4tPLnCjSh0Ypa8FVBtjTFacARJwwsY5zuZlkarFqzjLsxqVAdj6GjtZoX96w187m28kQokFB6TEkuWRfi43c8RnhhjRcEyn5P6a50YU7O4dAql00hlKinLLtc4PuJD/eO@@x8), same as C#

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```julia
n->n∈123:111:789
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNCgIxDIX3nuItW1Bo@pd2QC8iLroZGKllEAW9wZzTi9R0M5Bk8d735f6uS6FPn8@9nS7tt21k3UREE6fc1@fSXrWpUqt6lFXNx6vUsM7D@QAfIkJkRE4Q/Ka1PuxK@@4KLBzIyoz1ICeBJfEZzIyUDbIxIEMkgDPj@PGu/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
│ª▒=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RlKZDqx5Nm2T7/7@hkTGXoZEJl5GxCZexiSkQmwH5xiYA)

### Explanation

```
│       get differences of digits in integer
 ª      push [1]
  ▒     duplicate items in list
   =    pop(a, b), push(a==b)
```

Comment: It would be nice if `2.` could be `∞`

Comment: @JoKing yes, that would be the dream. Right now, `∞` multiplies each element of the list by 2 rather than multiplying the list by 2. I haven't checked if I use `∞` with lists to any extent, but I can't have both implementations at once. I also want to make `│` work with integers, to get digit differences which could be useful for some challenges.

Comment: @JoKing I realized that I could fit both those things into existing operators, which made sense to have. Check the readme for more changes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 36 bytes

```
0c75*2+3*&# :b9*8*`#0_# \%# -#0_1.@.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//83SDY31TLSNtZSU1awSrLUstBKUDaIV1aIUVVW0AWyDPUc9P7/NzWz5AIA)

Alternate version that uses the 2-D aspect of Befunge:

```
c75*2+3*&:98*b*`#v_\%-#v_1.@
                 >     >0. ^
```

I actually prefer the second, however the first is shorter.  Also, the first version leaves some stack pollution, whereas the second leaves a clean stack.  Either could easily be made for Befunge-93 with a small 4-byte addition.  I did not include it because there is already a 93 answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 11 bytes

```
ą₋Đ₋¬⇹Ʃ2=∧Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//SOujpu4jE4DEoTWP2nceW2lk@6hj@bkF//8bGhkbAwA)

```
ą              implicit input; convert to ąrray of characters
 ₋             reduce by subtraction
  Đ            Đuplicate
   ₋           reduce by subtaction
    ¬          logical NOT (coerce integer to boolean, then negate)
     ⇹         swap top two items on stack
      Ʃ        Ʃum
       2=      ... equals 2?
         ∧     logical AND
          Π    product; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṣk&⁼
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKx7uXJSt9qhxz5LipORiqOCCxYZGxhAmAA)

##### Explanation

```python
Ṣk&⁼  # Implicit input
Ṣ     # deltas
   ⁼  #        ==
 k&   #           [1, 1]
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 35 bytes

```
<?=($n=$argv[1]-99)<790&$n%111==24;
```

exploiting that the modulo of a negative number is never positive in PHP

Answer (score 0):

**C 61 Bytes**

```
f(char*v){puts(v[3]==0&v[0]+1==v[1]&v[1]+1==v[2]?"T":"F");}
g(v){puts(v<790&v%111==12?"T":"F");}
main(c, v)char**v;{
    f(v[1]);
    g(atoi(v[1]));
}
```

61 Bytes only includes the function. f(...)
36 Bytes using the trick from Geobits in g(...)

Answer (score 0):

## GNU Octave : 74 bytes

golfed:

```
function r=g(a)t=conv(a-'0',[1,-1],'valid')==1;r=(sum(t)==2).*prod(t);end;
```

ungolfed:

```
function r=golf_123(a)
  t=conv(a-'0',[1,-1],'valid')==1;
  r=(sum(t)==2).*prod(t);
endfunction
```

**Explanation**: Treat the string as an integer vector, any two consecutive digits will then have derivative given the finite difference filter [1,-1] equal to 1 at each valid convolution output. The prod command calculates product, so it will short circuit to 0 if at least one entry is 0. The sum(t)==2 disqualifies any run of increasing digits longer or shorter than 3.

Answer (score 0):

### JAVA 7, 57 bytes

```
boolean f(int x){return (int)Math.log(x)-1==3&x%111==12;}
```

Comment: You can remove the space in `return (int)`

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>33</s> <s>28</s> 27 Bytes

```
{$0=($1-12)/111~/^[1-7]$/}1
```

Prints `1` for corresponds to one of the desired values, `0` otherwise.

Updated answer is based on TimmyD's powershell answer.

Example usage:

```
awk '{$0=($1-12)/111~/^[1-7]$/}1' <<< 789
```

Prints `1`

```
awk '{$0=($1-12)/111~/^[1-7]$/}1' <<< 12
```

Prints `0`

Since this is using division rather than modulus, the result will be an integer for the desired values, but that integer needs to be between 1 and 7.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#FYqxDcMwDAT7n0NFXBjik5QoFZkksBcxktUVCvi/4nDrKfJ@FZ7Uo5L81fvDM65Sv1yLalBzmDd462g90GMgxgShMAxQc/sOWiplpoGIwJiCKQIKmYHJhm/8AQ)

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYqxDYAwDAT7n4MCChS/7cTJLAgkagagY/WQSP9XnO5@n97XhTt1SyS/dB3c41xS71SDmsM8w3NBLoESFVEbCIWhgjo276ANpRxpICJQm6CJgEKOwGTCJ34). Echoes for truthy, ignores for falsey.

Answer (score 0):

## SpecBAS - 35 bytes

```
1 INPUT n: ?(n-12)/111 in [1 TO 7]
```

Uses the same formula as the Powershell answer, returns 0 for False and 1 for True.

My original version was 59 bytes (and seems more "honest" for being my own work). Input as number and converted to string to avoid "012" showing as True.

```
1 INPUT n: n$=STR$ n: ?LEN n$=3 AND POS(n$,"0123456789")>0
```

Answer (score 0):

### C# 6 (36 bytes)

```
bool f(int x)=>x<790&0==(x+321)%111;
```

Comment: Is `f` necessary?

Answer (score 0):

## C, 71 bytes

Taking the input as `int`:

```
f,d,c;F(n){for(f=c=0;n;)d=n%10,c++,f|=d-(n/=10)%10-1&&n;return!f&c==3;}
```

Test main:

```
int main() {
  printf("%d\n", F(123));
  printf("%d\n", F(234));
  printf("%d\n", F(345));
  printf("%d\n", F(456));
  printf("%d\n", F(567));
  printf("%d\n", F(678));
  printf("%d\n", F(789));
  printf("%d\n", F(1));
  printf("%d\n", F(2));
  printf("%d\n", F(3));
  printf("%d\n", F(12));
  printf("%d\n", F(122));
  printf("%d\n", F(124));
  printf("%d\n", F(321));
  printf("%d\n", F(457));
  printf("%d\n", F(777));
  printf("%d\n", F(890));
  printf("%d\n", F(900));
  printf("%d\n", F(1011));
  printf("%d\n", F(1230));
  printf("%d\n", F(1234));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 114 bytes

```
i = gets.chomp.to_i
l = [123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789]
y=false
l.each {|x| if i==x then y=true end;}
puts y
```

I don't know how many bytes this answer is, but I'm guessing it's not that small.

Comment: Do you need those spaces?

Comment: You can remove all but one space (`puts y`).`.each` can be `.map`. `false` can be `p`. `if i==x then y=true end;` can be `i==x&&y=1`

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 48 bytes

```
(defn f [n] (= n ((set (range 123 900 111)) n)))
```

Test:

```
user=> (map (fn [n] [n (f n)]) [123 234 345 456 567 678 789])
([123 true]
 [234 true]
 [345 true]
 [456 true]
 [567 true]
 [678 true]
 [789 true])

user=> (map (fn [n] [n (f n)]) [1 2 3 12 122 124 132 321 457 777 890 900 1011 1230 1234])
([1 false]
 [2 false]
 [3 false]
 [12 false]
 [122 false]
 [124 false]
 [132 false]
 [321 false]
 [457 false]
 [777 false]
 [890 false]
 [900 false]
 [1011 false]
 [1230 false]
 [1234 false])
```

Comment: I swear I didn't copy your answer! This can be significantly reduced. See my answer which is the same idea, but without all of the extra bits.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 5.6, 48 bytes

```php
<?=($a=$argv[1])==join("",range($a[0],$a[0]+2));
```

Wanted to try something a little different from the other PHP answers (and a different approach to most of the posted answers). Take the first number of the input string, add two to it and create a `range` array, then join those together to create a new string and then return if they're equal or not.

Run with:

```php
echo '<?=($a=$argv[1])==join("",range($a[0],$a[0]+2));' | php -- 123
```

Answer (score 0):

## ><> (Fish), 28 Bytes

```
l3-0=?v0n;>
?+1-@:<;n1^?+2-!
```

Input is via an execution argument to add each digit to stack, left to right.

Checks if the length of the stack (number) is three, then that there's a difference of one between the third and second digits, then that there's a difference of two between the first and third digits.

[Try it online!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/TAMx9DEK6cgDPqXJ8)

Answer (score 0):

### Jelly, 8 bytes

Not as short as Dennis's answer (duh), but I'm quite proud of myself for getting the results I wanted out of Jelly.

```
9Rṡ3
De¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@28Z9HDnQmMul9RDi/7//29oaAIA)

Explanation:

```
9R    Push 1-9 to the stack
ṡ3    Slice up the stack in parts of 3, overlapping
      This gives us [1,2,3], [2,3,4], ..., [7,8,9]
D     Convert input to list ( '123' -> [1, 2, 3])
e¢    This checks to see if the decimal list is in the list of our previous link.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 25 bytes

```
(set (range 123 790 111))
```

Basically the Haskell answer. Creates a range which includes all the truthy answers, then converts it into a set. Sets are functions in Clojure (they implement the function interface and can be called).

Returns the number as the truthy return (every number is truthy in Clojure), and `nil` for the falsey value.

Use:

```
(let [s (set (range 123 790 111))]

    (s 123)
    123

    (s 234)
    234

    (s 993)
    nil
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 27 bytes

```
INPUT N?N-12==N DIV&H64*111
```

[Using Dennis's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91604/48934).

If forcing the user to add `&H` to their input is OK, this works for 24 bytes:

```
INPUT N?N-18==(N>>8)*273
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 21 bytes

```
;[7|~!12+111*a$=A|_Xq
```

This prints `1` if a match is found, nothing otherwise.

Explanation

```
;              Get A$ from the command line
[7|            FOR a=1; a <=7 ; a++ (for each of the 7 sequences)
  12+111*a     Generate the number 123, 234, 345 by mult. 111 x index, plus 12
 !        $    Cast that to string B$
~          =A  And IF that matches A$
|_Xq           THEN quit, printing 1
               IF and FOR loop implicitly closed
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>57</s> 53 bytes

```
#@ #.0 &# ::57*2+3*%34*-#<_# 34*`!#<_# 98*34**`#<_1.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@6/soKCsZ6CgpqxgZWVqrmWkbaylamyipatsE6@sAGQkKIJZlhZaQI5WApBjqOfw/7@JqTEA)

Explanation

```
#@ #.0        skip the terminator and output command. Adds a meaningless zero to 
                the stack.
&# ::         take in an input and add two more copies to the stack
57*2+3*%      adds input mod 111 ((5*7+2)*3) to the stack
34*-#<_#      compares 12 to the result, if they are the same, continue to move 
                right, else move left
34*`!#<_#     checks to see that the input is greater (`) than 12. If it is, 
                continue to move right, else move left
98*34**`#<_   check that 864 (9*8*3*4) is greater than the input. (the reason for 
                this is that 864 was an easy number to create that was greater than 
                the last possible number (789) and was less than the next number 
                divisible by 111 (900)
1.@           if you pass all the checks, output 1, otherwise...
@.0># &#      you will move back through the code heading left. (you will do 
                the operations, but that will not matter.) Skip the input 
                command. Output zero and end the code.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Thue, 84 bytes

```
123z::=~1
234z::=~1
345z::=~1
456z::=~1
567z::=~1
678z::=~1
789z::=~1
a::=:::
::=
az
```

Outputs `1` when given one of the target values, and no output when given something else. The `z` at the end is needed to prevent false positives with numbers like `1230`

Answer (score 0):

## Unexpanded Sinclair ZX-81 and Timex TS1000/1500 <strike>~99</strike> 97 tokenised BASIC bytes

```
 1 LET A$="123456789"
 2 INPUT B$
 3 LET P=NOT PI
 4 FOR F=VAL "1" TO VAL "7"
 5 LET P=P+(A$(F TO F+VAL "2")=B$)
 6 NEXT F
 7 PRINT P
```

This is using a sub-string method to scan the string literal `A$` for the match as per the test cases; if a match is found then the variable `1` is added to the `P`, otherwise zero is added to `P`.

[image: Donkeysoft - Easy as one-two-three]

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 40 chars, 80 bytes

```
{(∼⍵⊆⎕D)∨3≠≢⍵:0⋄(⊂⍎¨⍕⍵)∊{⍵+0..2}¨⍳7:1⋄0}
```

This is a little long, but would return the 0 if type is not string, or if string is different "123","234",..,"789";  test:

```
  f←{(∼⍵⊆⎕D)∨3≠≢⍵:0⋄(⊂⍎¨⍕⍵)∊{⍵+0..2}¨⍳7:1⋄0} 
  f 'aaa'
0
  f ''
0
  f¨('12')(,'3')('3')('122')('124')('132')('123456789')
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  f¨('123')('456')('789')
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 27 bytes

```
$[n][∧12=n%111n<=>13 789]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Ehdpsu)

```
$[n][                      ; a function taking an argument n
              n<=>13 789   ; is n between 13 and 789?
     ∧                     ; and
      12=n%111             ; is n mod 111 equal to 12?
                         ] ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 8 \log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
dz[11dA=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrUqqiDQ1THG0hXKjogsWGRsYQJgA)

Port of Emigna's 05AB1E answer.